# How to move field to the top when others field at top blank

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I haved created 5 parameters field at page header.When the parameter key in nothing then it will appear blank. My problem is how to make the parameter P_2 move to the top when  parameter P_1 key in nothnig.

Comment: What do you mean "move to the top"?

Comment: Do you want to use Java API (JasperReports or DynamicJasper)?

Comment: I mean if first field contain no data then it have space between first field and other field below. For your information i create field at page header, the field will display parameter that I key in. i want to use dynamic jasper.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish this pretty easily with jasper-reports. Set your fields to `Blank When Null = true` and `Remove Line When Blank = true`.

Comment: Its work when I arrange the field from top to bottom. But if I arrange the field left and right its doesn't work.

Comment: well that wasn't your question now was it? To accomplish that you'll have to create 5 fields and then write the appropriate conditional logic in each one so that the correct value shows in each depending on your parameter values. (It's going to be a bunch of ternary if clauses). Or you'll have to convert it to a crosstab style report or  handle it in your query.